# rviz to create png/jpeg maps of the environment

Tags: gazebo, simulation, rviz, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I use rviz (with stage/gazebo) to obtain progressively better maps with time ? Can I get that map in png/jpeg format ?

May be a noobish question - any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11647/rviz-to-create-png/jpeg-maps-of-the-environment/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2011-10-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LiMuBei](https://answers.ros.org/users/68/limubei/) on 2011-10-24**:
What kind of map? rviz is only a visualization tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The short answer is "no", but the longer answer is "yes".

`rviz` is just a visualization tool; it just lets you watch what's happening. If you want to generate maps, you want the [slam_gmapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping) stack (in particular, the `gmapping` package), which is the standard way to do (2D, laser-rangefinder) SLAM in ROS. There's nothing special about stage or gazebo; as far as GMapping is concerned, their data is just as good as the data from a real robot.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-01-16**:
@Mac : Hi again, just wanted to ask you - using gmapping and mapserver with gazebo - does that give a pgm SLAM map ? I am trying to work out SLAM with gazebo - not really much has worked out ! :-(

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-11-10**:
@Mac : Thanks, never tried it, not really great with gazebo .....

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-11-10**:
Certainly. Why wouldn't it be?

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-11-09**:
@Mac : Is  it possible to make such SLAM maps using gazebo ?

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-11-02**:
@Mac : http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage/Tutorials/MakingMapsUsingStagesWanderController

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-10-31**:
That tutorial might be worth putting in a more-visible place; maybe on the stage or gmapping wiki pages? I'm not sure what the right place is.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-10-29**:
@Mac : Working pretty nicely, I have put together a tutorial of sorts ! .... http://mobotica.blogspot.com/2011/10/maps-from-stage-simulations-in-ros.html

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-10-25**:
You're welcome; go ahead and accept my answer, too (the checkmark icon).

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-10-25**:
@Mac : I have started getting some results using the map server - accuracy is not the strong point right now - but stage marries well with gmapping and map server. Thank you once again.

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-10-25**:
I don't, I'm afraid. Still, this is a standard use case, and should be well-supported.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-10-25**:
@Mac : Thank you - do you have any examples of such (viz. stage + gmapping) ?

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-10-25**:
It certainly can.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-10-25**:
@Mac : Can stage/stageros function in tandem with gmapping ? Simulation in stageros and map of the same in gmapping ?